# How do you make an count-up timer in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, timer

I have looked everywhere but I cannot find out how to do so. I need a simple timer that can count up in milliseconds and can be stopped. (XCode 3.1, Objective-C, **iPhone OS Development**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I just being daft or is "count-up timer" the same as a stopwatch.

If it is, check out this [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jmTQi98vec)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code which i have done one timer with minute, second, and mili seconds.. So, its helpful for you. And also do it release after not use..

```
-(void)showTime:(NSTimer *)sender
    {
        miniSeconds++;
        if (miniSeconds == 10)
        {
            miniSeconds = 0;
            seconds++;
            if (seconds == 60)
            {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
            }
        }
        timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i",minutes,seconds,miniSeconds];
    }
    -(void)nextLevelTime
    {
        [labelTimer invalidate];
        miniSeconds = 0;
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = 0;
    }
```

The nextLevel method use for to stop timer and release all thing..

Use it, I have done with this code..

Comment: miniseconds, seconds, and minutes are not declared. how would I declare them?

Comment: If this answer helpful for you than accept it.. So, other can use as per their require... Thanks...

Comment: I am a complete noob at coding so can you write me a sample code of how to define them?

Comment: ok Lets see, minutes, seconds , miniseconds are NSInteger.. timerLabel is a UILabel , ShowTimer is a method to pass from timer.. like     [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(showTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; Like that. Now you understand whole concept. I hope so..

Answer (score 0):

NSTimer should do it:

[Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

[Timer Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000061i)

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController()
{
UILabel *progress;
    NSTimer *timer;
    int currMinute;
    int currSeconds;
    int currHours;
}
@end


@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    progress=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 15, 100, 50)];
    progress.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [progress setText:@"Time : 00:00:00"];
    progress.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:progress];
    currMinute=00;
    currSeconds=00;
    currHours=00;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)start
{
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)timerFired
{
    currSeconds+=1;
    if(currSeconds==60)
    {
        currSeconds=0;
        currMinute+=1;
        if(currMinute==60)
        {
            currMinute=0;
            currHours+=1;

        }
    }
    [_progress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%02d%@%02d%@%02d",@"Time : ",currHours,@":",currMinute,@":",currSeconds]];

    if(currMinute==2)//stop at 2 minute
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```